# Calculate aggregated interval data in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery as below

```
activity    userid            activity_date       activity_time        value
running         xyz           2023-02-26          2023-02-26 13:00:00 UTC   5
running         xyz           2023-02-26          2023-02-26 13:01:00 UTC   4
running         xyz           2023-02-26          2023-02-26 13:02:00 UTC   7
running         xyz           2023-03-26          2023-02-26 13:03:00 UTC   8
running         xyz           2023-03-26          2023-02-26 13:04:00 UTC   3
```

Records in the table is the minutes data for each day. I need to calculate some aggregated values like sum(value), min(value), max(value) group by activity_date but that will give me daily aggregate. I need to calculate 15 minutes, 1 hour sum, min and max values for a given date as well.

Please suggest how this can be achieved writing a SQL

Tried timestamp functions

Comment: Just to be clear: you want 3 different queries? And also, are you expecting rows for timeslots where was no activity with zeroes or are you expecting lack of such rows?

Comment: I am actually looking to display result using one query. KInd of grouping by records on 15 min and 1 hour intervals and then apply aggregate function. For example I want to see sum(value) as 'Daily total', sum(value) as 'hourly total' and sum(value) as '15 minutes total'. If not possible in one query then multiple queries. There are timeslots with no activities so now rows

Comment: Then I don't understand your vision of output. Please [edit] the question and add the expected output (preferably as a table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) query.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, DATE '2023-02-26' activity_date, TIMESTAMP '2023-02-26 13:00:00 UTC' activity_time, 5 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-02-26' activity_date, '2023-02-26 13:01:00 UTC' activity_time, 4 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-02-26' activity_date, '2023-02-26 13:02:00 UTC' activity_time, 7 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-03-26' activity_date, '2023-03-26 13:03:00 UTC' activity_time, 8 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-03-26' activity_date, '2023-03-26 13:04:00 UTC' activity_time, 3 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-03-26' activity_date, '2023-03-26 23:14:00 UTC' activity_time, 4 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-03-26' activity_date, '2023-03-26 23:24:00 UTC' activity_time, 5 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-03-26' activity_date, '2023-03-26 23:34:00 UTC' activity_time, 9 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'running' activity, 'xyz' userid, '2023-03-26' activity_date, '2023-03-26 23:54:00 UTC' activity_time, 5 value
)
SELECT -- 5 dimensions
       activity, userid,
       activity_date AS dim_date,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM activity_time) dim_hour,
       -- minutes are normalized from 0 to 3.
       DIV(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM activity_time), 15) dim_minute,
       -- 3 metircs : sum, min, max
       SUM(value) sum, MIN(value) min, MAX(value) max
  FROM sample_table
       -- rollup dimensions
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
HAVING activity IS NOT NULL AND userid IS NOT NULL AND dim_date IS NOT NULL;
```

**Query results**

[image]

In above result,

- If `dim_hour` and `dim_minute` is *null*, metrics are `Daily` aggregation.
- If `dim_hour` is *not null* and `dim_minute` is *null*, metrics are `Hourly` aggregation.
- If `dim_hour` and `dim_minute` is *not null*, metrics are `15-minute` aggregation.